# Keyword `default` for constructor and destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default, destructor

For given class:

```
class C
{
    // ...
}
```

What's the difference between

```
class C
{
    // ...
    C() { };
    ~C() { };
    // ...
}
```

and

```
class C
{
    // ...
    C() = default;
    ~C() = default;
    // ...
}
```

?

Are they doing the same?

Comment: Are you sure that you want ctor/dtor to be private?

Comment: Possibly also interesting in this context: `C(/* ... */) = delete;`, which explicitly forbids the compiler to generate a default constructor.

Comment: @KarlisOlte of course, I mean public, the question is not about visibility